# How to get adjacent cells of 3 smallest numbers in order?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I need 3 smallest numbers and corresponding cells. As you see first two 2s are `A` and the last one is `O`, but the output gives me `A` anyways. I would like to get them from the top to the bottom, so my output should be `A, A, O`, not `A, A, A`. Here are formulas of these `A, A, A`. Thanks.

```
=VLOOKUP(SMALL($E$26:$E$34;1); $E$26:$F$34; 2; 0)
=VLOOKUP(SMALL($E$26:$E$34;2); $E$26:$F$34; 2; 0)
=VLOOKUP(SMALL($E$26:$E$34;3); $E$26:$F$34; 2; 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would be A way to do it:

```
=INDEX(SORTBY(FILTER(E26:F34,E26:E34<=SMALL(E26:E34,3)),FILTER(E26:E34,E26:E34<=SMALL(E26:E34,3)),1),SEQUENCE(3),2)
```

The first filter takes cells that qualify from both columns (which may be more than three if there are "ties." The second filter provides just the first column's contributions to the `SORTBY` as the sort range. If there are "ties" with any of the results from the first one, this sort maintains the original order rather than doing a secondary sort of the letter column. That means the first/higher/top element in the ties comes first in them.

`INDEX` then simply takes only the first three of however many qualified catching only the highest from the letters if, say, two values made up the three smallest and the higher of the two had two or more ties. Hard for me to say, somehow, but it's what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks. Gonna approve this as an answer as I currently don't have Office 365 which the other answer requires.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you ca use a combination of `TAKE` and `SORT` functions.

```
=TAKE(SORT(E26:F34),3,-1)
```

- SORT(E26:F34): Sort the array by ascending order (of the first column as other arguments are not stipulated).
- TAKE(SORT(E26:F34),3,-1: From the resulting sorted arry, select the first 3 rows and select the last column (-1).

[image]